# Как отобразить нескольких графиков по данным одних и тех же столбцов?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, визуализация

Есть фрейм данных со столбцами `(Date,Type,Location,Price)`.

Нужно построить графики (каждый - на отдельной картинке) зависимости `Price` от `Date` для каждого `Type` в двух столбцах. Число столбцов (2) должно определяться количеством и названиями `Location`.

Перебираю в цикле фрейм и он рисует нужное количество графиков, указывая в них названия в соответствии с `Type`. То есть, на каждый `Type` по графику. При этом, сами графики не отличаются друг от друга, то есть содержимое всех `Type` перемешивается.

Я использую код:

```
dat = pd.read_csv('ap-northeast-1.csv', parse_dates = True, names=['Date','Type','OS', 'Location', 'Price'])
da = dat[dat.OS == 'Windows']
del da['OS']
del da['Location']
date = []
for d in da["Date"]:
    d = str(d)
    date.append(d[:10])
da["Date"] = date
df = da.loc[da.Type.str.startswith('i')]
for name, data in df.groupby('Type'):
    plt.plot(df['Date'], df['Price'])
    plt.title(name)
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Price')
    plt.xticks(rotation = 'vertical')
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

Видимо, проблема в том, что в `plt.plot(df['Date'], df['Price'])`
нет переменной `name`. Как ее добавить, чтобы в каждом графике рисовалось только то, что относится к отдельному `Type`?

[Сет данных](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lNZHzYBdYqK_Ip3G-eNNUzcfiLgWDgNE/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: а зачем вам еще один account? Что не так с https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/422263/andrew-tim ?

Comment: Добавил ссылки на датасет и свой вариант решения.

Comment: Свой вариант решения должен быть в теле вопроса (по правилам форума)...

Comment: Добавил весь свой код.

Comment: можете пояснить что вы имели ввиду под словами `Видимо, проблема в том, что нет переменной name.` Откуда должно браться значения для `name`?

Comment: Значение name берется за каждый Type при прогоне таблицы в цикле. И значения name для каждого график таблицы разное, число графиков соответствует числу различных Type. Другими словами: если в столбце Type есть в рандомном порядке 'a', 'b' и 'c' много раз, то в результате мы получаем три графика с соответствующими названиями. Только пока что на каждом из этих графиков одинаково изображены вперемешку содержимые каждого из трех графиков.

Comment: Отсюда и моя уверенность в том, что name нужно как-то приладить к упомянутой в вопросе строке в цикле, чтобы он плотил в график по имени name только Date и Price, которые относятся к этому name, а не всё.

Comment: Что Вы имеете в виду? Дополнить исходный вопрос новыми подробностями?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Построение отдельных графиков для каждого `Type`:

```
(df
 .set_index("Date")
 .groupby("Type")
 .apply(lambda x: x[["Price"]].plot(grid=True, title=x.name)))
```

Comment: Ответ как бы подошел, но а если к данной задаче появился еще вопрос, то его задавать отдельно или еще можно отредактировать исходный вопрос?

Comment: @AndrewTim, если это маленькое уточнение, то можно дописать его в вопрос, а если дополнительные вопросы, то лучше задать новый вопрос

Comment: Я затрудняюсь оценить масштаб этого уточнения. Обновил.

Comment: Всё же задам уже новый вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

попробуйте так:

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df.pivot_table(index="Date", columns="Type", values="Price", aggfunc="mean").plot()
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, но что с первой строкой, что без нее - результат одинаков, и он отличается от Вашего только тем, что у меня легенда со всеми Type находится в центре графика. А мне нужно по одному графику на каждый Type, потому я и пытаюсь организовать это в цикле.

Comment: Т.е. вам нужны отдельные графики?

Comment: Да. Потому в цикле. Более того - ранее у меня было задание (успешно выполненное), где в две строчки программа разбрасывала аналогичную таблицу на десяток .csv-файлов, каждый из которых носил свое название и содержимое этих файлов не перемешивалось между собой. В решаемой сейчас задаче логика та же - имена графиков уже разные (и их количество адекватно числу значений *Type*, но вот сами графики в куче. Отсюда и моя уверенность в том, что name нужно как-то приладить к упомянутой в вопросе строке в цикле.